# fields_for options documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am hoping I am missing something obvious.  I want to see what the available `options` are that you can pass into the rails `fields_for` method via the `options` hash argument.

I looked at the [fields_for documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) and there is no section that displays what all the available options are.  For example: some of the comments below mention that their is a `child_index` option you can pass in.

**Question**: Are there other options for `fields_for`?  Is there official documentation, or documention anywhere, that explains all available options for `fields_for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my digging around, it looks like you can pass in either `index` or `child_index`

Looking at the initialization method of the Rails FormBuilder (which gets called for every form), you can see that it has no defaults and really only checks for those values I mentioned above:

```
# rails/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb
# lines 1284 - 1297

def initialize(object_name, object, template, options)
  @nested_child_index = {}
  @object_name, @object, @template, @options = object_name, object, template, options
  @default_options = @options ? @options.slice(:index, :namespace) : {}  ### < NO DEFAULTS
  if @object_name.to_s.match(/\[\]$/)
    if object ||= @template.instance_variable_get("@#{Regexp.last_match.pre_match}") and object.respond_to?(:to_param)
      @auto_index = object.to_param
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "object[] naming but object param and @object var don't exist or don't respond to to_param: #{object.inspect}"
    end
  end
  @multipart = nil

  @index = options[:index] || options[:child_index]    ### < CHECKS FOR VALUES
end
```

I've added comments in the source above to help point out my findings.

**Helpful links:**

- [View source on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1091d746c9fac4b056ad7597bdd37a07e6283bfd/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1296)
- [View FormBuilder Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html)